# Equality of two sets in Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces

Let us define the sets:
$$
A=\{u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega):\int_{\Omega}u\,dx=0\}
$$
and
$$
B=\{u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega):\int_{\Omega}|u|^{q-2}u\,dx=0\}.
$$
Here $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ denotes the usual Sobolev space, where $\Omega$ is a bounded smooth domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $1<p<n$ and $1<q<p^*=\frac{np}{n-p}$. Let us define
$$
\lambda_A=\inf_{u\in A}\{\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^p\,dx:\int_{\Omega}|u|^q\,dx=1\}
$$
and
$$
\lambda_B=\inf_{u\in B}\{\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^p\,dx:\int_{\Omega}|u|^q\,dx=1\}.
$$

My question: Is $\lambda_A=\lambda_B$? I tried to understand, but I could not able to see at least one inequality. Can someone please help. Thanks.

Comment: My first guess would be no in general; if $p=q\neq 2$, then these are the best constants of certain Poincaré inequalities on different classes of functions. I don't have a counterexample at the moment though.

Comment: Thanks. I agree with you. Please comment if you come up with some counterexample. Thanks.